# puppet parameterised classes

Tags: puppet

I am having trouble getting parameterised classes working in puppet 2.6.4 (client and master)

```
######## from /etc/puppet/manifests/nodes.pp 
# defining one node to use certain version
#######################################################
node 'dev-internal-000008.domain.com' {
         include software($version="dev-2011.02.11")
}
```

# from /etc/puppet/modules/software/manifests/init.pp

## I am setting the version here as the "default"

#

```
class software($version="dev-2011.02.04b") {
  File {
    links => follow
  }

  file { "/opt/software_AIR":
    ensure => directory
  }

  file { "/opt/software_AIR/share":
    source => "puppet://puppet/software/air/$version",
    recurse => "true",
  }
}
```

#

errors from puppet master

#

```
err: Could not parse for environment production: Syntax error at '='; expected ')' at /etc/puppet/manifests/nodes.pp:10 on node dev-internal-domain.com
```

#

found a fix for this

try

```
node 'dev-internal-000008.domain.com' {
  class { customsoftware:version => "dev-2011.02.04b" }
}
```

Comment: My syntax was wrong in the nodes.pp.. node 'dev-internal-000008.domain.com' {
  class { customsoftware:version => "dev-2011.02.04b" }
}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parameterized classes don't work with `include`, unfortunately. You have to use the [new alternate class declaration syntax](https://puppet.com/blog/modeling-class-composition-parameterized-classes/) that was introduced at the same time as parameterized classes:

```
node 'dev-internal-000008.domain.com' {
    # include software($version="dev-2011.02.11") # (doesn't work)
    class {'software':
        version => "dev-2011.02.11",
    } # works
}
```

Things:

- Note that it looks like a resource (`file`, `service`, etc.) declaration.
- The fact that the definition and the declaration both start with the word class is confusing, but be careful and you'll be fine.
- You can't declare a class this way more than once, the way you can with `include`. This is expected to change in 2.7, and some friendlier syntax will likely be introduced.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a selector based on hostname:

```
class {'software':
    version         => $::hostname ? {
      /hostname1/   => 'dev-2011.02.11',
      default       => 'dev-2011.02.04b',
    },
}
```